# How can I reference a word in Sheet1 using a code through VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Reference Word Photo
[image]

I have attached a photo of my workbook where my command button is located. Within my code, I need to include the current month and the previous month names and would like the code to reference both July and June.

Macro Code Photo

[image]

In the previous month section I would like it to reference June in cell B15 of Sheet1 and July in cell B14 of Sheet1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure I really understand the question you have... Do you simply want to insert the name of the current and previous month into those two cells?

Comment: @daZza I want to be able to change the months and the macro code automatically update once I enter the new months...ex) July and August, August and September

Comment: So you want to adapt your code based on the months in B14 and B15?

Comment: @daZza Yes because cells B14 and B15 will constantly be changing so I do not want to have it hardcoded within the macro

Comment: @ScottHoltzman where would I include the second part sPrevMon = Range("B1")? Would that be in place of Previous Month and Current Month within the code?

Comment: Well, that's rather easy. Just change the code to reference the Cell instead of hardcoding a string. You might want to implement a plausibility check though. ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B14").Value

Comment: @JHags - see my answer and yes, replace the current lines where you hard code "Previous Month" and "Current Month". Also, in the future, copy and paste your code into your question, instead of using screenshots. It makes it possible for us to copy the code and test it for you when we suggest answers.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman But I need the reference to be from Sheet1 to include June and July, I do not want it to say Previous Month and Current Month

Comment: See my answer. Assigning this `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B14").Value` to a variable will result in the variable storing the exact value from cell b14. In your case "July" (or next month "August"). Whenever you reference the variable in your code it will have the name of the month in it.

Comment: @JHags - the variables `sPrevMon` will be June and `sCurrMon` will be July (or whatever the value on the worksheet says. You can then use those variables in the code to mean whatever months are written in the worksheet. See more on [using variables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/843144)

Answer (score 0):

Load the value of the range directly into a string variable. Here is how to do that:

Replace these lines in the code:

```
Sheets("MoM").Select
Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "Previous Month"
Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "Current Month"
```

With this:

```
With Sheets("MoM")

    Dim sPrevMon as String
    Dim sCurrMon as String

    'load value into variable
    sPrevMon = .Range("B15").Value 
    sCurrMon = .Range("B14").Value

    'write value to cell
    .Range("B1") = sCurrMon
    .Range("C1") = sPrevMon

    'use value in code
    Msgbox "Current Month is " & sCurrMon & ". Previous month was " & sPrevMon

End With
```

Whenever you need the month names just pass `sPrevMon` and `sCurrMon`.

For more on using variables, read [this MSDN article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/843144)

Comment: where am I referencing the Previous Month and the Current Month in terms of June and July?

Comment: @JHags - see my edits, I originally messed up the range references

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim curMonth as String
Dim prevMonth as String

[...]
prevMonth = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B15").Value
curMonth = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B14").Value

'implement plausibility check if needed --> String in "January", "February", ...

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value = curMonth
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C1").Value = prevMonth

[...]
```

Whenever you want to reference the current or previous month in your code, reference to the appropriate variables.

Comment: Thank you but I need the ranges from both B14 and B15 to be then put into Range B1 and C1....so in the sheet, cell B1 would say June and cell C1 would say July

Comment: Ok, I didn't get that from your question. Edited the post, although Scott has already done so above as well